# useMutation result returning weird structure/ not returning requested fields

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, apollo

**What I am trying to do:** using useMutation to submit an array of array to mongoDB.

**What happened:** it did successfully save in mongoDb and in the correct format **BUT** the 'result.data' of useMutation is not as expected, it's too weired to be used.

This is my array of array (of course, it started as an empty array and was pushed in as user adds attraction to the days in their itinerary).

```
let itinerary = [{placeIds: ["ChIJafBhcoVPqEcRb7rHEy3G0L8", "ChIJBRk3gUlOqEcR9oEBV-dqK5M"]},
{placeIds: ["ChIJx8Iw5VFOqEcRXUgfWxkmAaA", "ChIJSdWeck5OqEcReSTr3YfoSuE"]}, 
{placeIds: ["ChIJ1WCXcFJOqEcRBR_ICa3TemU"]}]
```

This is the graphql mutation:

```
const SUBMIT_ITINERARY =  gql`
        mutation submitItinerary(
            $dayPlans: [DayPlanInput]
        ){
            submitItinerary(
                dayPlans: $dayPlans
            ){
                id
                dayPlans{
                    placeIds
                }
                createdAt
            }
        }
    `
```

This is the apollo react hook useMutation:

```
const [submitItinerary] = useMutation(SUBMIT_ITINERARY, {
        update(result){
            console.log(result.data);
        },
        onError(err){
            console.log(err)
        },
        variables: {
            dayPlans: itinerary
        }
    })
```

in my graphql playground I got this
[image: screenshot of graphql]

So I thought in my frontend I would get something similar but instead I got this:
[image: screenshot of frontend console]

**Why is that the case?** I want to get a structure similar to what I got in graphql playground.

---

**More information that might be helpful:**
Here is my itinerary schema:

```
const itinerarySchema = new Schema({
    city: String,
    username: String,
    createdAt: String,
    dayPlans: [],
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
    }
});
```

my type definitions:

```
type DayPlan {
    placeIds: [String]!
}
type Itinerary {
    id: ID!
    dayPlans: [DayPlan]!
    username: String!
    createdAt: String!
}
input DayPlanInput {
    placeIds: [String]
}
input RegisterInput {
    username: String!
    password: String!
    confirmPassword: String!
    email: String!
}
type Query {
    getUsers: [User]
}
type Mutation {
    register(registerInput: RegisterInput): User!
    login(username: String!, password: String!): User!
    submitItinerary(dayPlans: [DayPlanInput] ): Itinerary!
}
```

and my submitItinerary resolver:

```
Mutation: {
        async submitItinerary(_, {dayPlans}, context) {
            const user = checkAuth(context);
            //console.log(user);

            if (dayPlans.length === 0){
                throw new Error('Itinerary should not be empty');
            }

            const newItinerary = new Itinerary({
                dayPlans,
                user: user.id,
                username: user.username,
                createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
            })

            const submitted = await newItinerary.save()

            return submitted;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first variable of the `update` option in `useMutation` is the Apollo Cache itself not the mutation result. The mutation result can be found in the second parameter. [Here you can find the API docs.](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#options-2)

This should log the correct data:

```
const [submitItinerary] = useMutation(SUBMIT_ITINERARY, {
    update(cache, result){
        console.log(result.data);
    },
    onError(err){
        console.log(err)
    },
    variables: {
        dayPlans: itinerary
    }
})
```

Also another way to access the mutation result is using the second element from the hook return value:

```
const [submitItinerary, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(SUBMIT_ITINERARY)
```